# ExpandableListView inside ExpandableListView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I would like to know if it is possible to put an ExpandableListView as one child of one element of another ExpandableListView. Thanks

Comment: Checkout this lightweight implementation https://github.com/shahbazhashmi/nested-expandable-recyclerview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

yes.It is possible to create the expandable listview inside the expandable listview.

Follow the bellow link.It demonstrates the 3_level expandable listview.

http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2011/02/3-level-expandable-lists.html

Answer (score 0):

I personally tried this situation and its almost impossible to handle expandable list operations. If you put a second expandable list view into first one's child then the second one cannot open the first one when it is expanded. (the root ELV does not resize) Also the if the child ELV  has too much children then it is opening incredibly slow.

Give up if you try to find such a solution. the only way I found is to implement a listview behaving like a listview. This is the best solution I have ever found and implemented. [This is the link.](http://twocentscode.blogspot.com.tr/2014/02/three-level-expandable-listview.html)

It can be nested and implemented as infinite level.

Answer (score -1):

Yes definitely we can put one ExpandableListView as a child of the other ExpandableListView
Try this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)