# Expandable list view inside another expandable list view for tree like implementation

Tags: android

hi I have a doubt is it possible to place the expandable list view inside the another expandable list view??
if yes how to make the inner expandable list view match_parent with all the items showing after expanded??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpandableListView inside ExpandableListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401640/expandablelistview-inside-expandablelistview)